# Concurrent execution of map-reduce causes Class Cast Exceptption

Tags: hadoop, concurrency, mapreduce

I am using hadoop-core-1.2.0. I am trying to execute 8 concurrent map-reduce job.

ExecutonService is used to submit the job. But when program is ran, it gives following exception

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplit
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplit
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:406)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

I could not find answer for this on google. Few more people are having same problem. According to [link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-common-user/201112.mbox/%3C33022696.post@talk.nabble.com%3E) it happens because concurrent call to waitForCompletion.

Kindly help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the import of FileSplit with org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit in your job .

Comment: Surprisingly I am not importing FileSplit any any of the class file throughout the project. If we look at the stack trace, none of the local source files are referred.

Comment: I downgraded hadoop core api to 0.20 and it is working great. But I still need to figure out the solution for 1.2.0